# Execute CURL with kubectl

Tags: kubernetes

Пытаюсь выполнить команду:

```
kubectl exec pod_name -- sh -c curl -X 'POST' \
  'http://localhost:8080/service1/api/rest/startNewJob' \
  -H 'Authorization: Basic ZG92c34lbmE7ZG45U03lbmEmMjT0' \
  -H 'accept: application/json' \
  -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
  -d '{"jobName":"service2"}'
```

После выполнения получаю ошибку "command terminated with exit code 2" скриншот ниже.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Если зайти в внутрь пода и попытаться выполнить:

```
curl -X 'POST' \
      'http://localhost:8080/service1/api/rest/startNewJob' \
      -H 'Authorization: Basic ZG92c34lbmE7ZG45U03lbmEmMjT0' \
      -H 'accept: application/json' \
      -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
      -d '{"jobName": "service2"}'
```

То команда выполняется без ошибок. Предполагаю что нужно где-то поставить правильно кавычки, только вот где не знаю.

**Разобрался где нужно ставить кавычки, плюс нужно было экранировать кавычки в запросе JSON. Рабочий пример ниже, работает только в bash:**

```
kubectl exec pod_name -- sh -c "curl -X 'POST' \
'http://localhost:8080/service1/api/rest/startNewJob' \
-H 'Authorization: Basic ZG92c34lbmE7ZG45U03lbmEmMjT0' \
-H 'accept: application/json' \
-H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
-d '{\"jobName\":\"service2\"}'"
```